# Compile Error when using Spring JMS

Tags: java, spring, jms, jmstemplate

I'm running into a compile error while trying to use Spring-JMS.  A quick Google search only turned up one matching result, but I was unable to get anything useful out of it.

I'm using the following code:

```
public class Class extends AbstractClass {

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void acceptImportableItem(final ImportableItem<File> item) {
        JmsOperations template = getJmsTemplate();

        template.convertAndSend(item);
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, I receive the following compile error:

```
cannot access javax.jms.Destination
```

and

```
class file for javax.jms.Destination not found
```

Nowhere in my code to I reference javax.jms.Destination.  Do any of you have any idea why that error would crop up?

Comment: Do you have jms.jar or similar in the classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JmsOperations requires the javax jms classes for some of its methods, so you need them in your build path. You are going to need your JMS provider's implementations on your classpath at runtime, anyway.

Comment: Spring abstracts complexity of jms from developer; internaly it uses interfaces provided by javax.jms classes.

Comment: It's odd that my source doesn't reference any of this stuff.

That said, you're correct: it is needed at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using activemq and in my case it was solved by adding this to the pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```